# Can I hide a input and show a label?

Tags: php

I have inputs with data on her value from database like this:

```
<input type="text" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">
<input type="text" name="AGE" value="<?php echo $row['AGE'];?>">
```

How can I hide the inputs and show a label when exist data on the row and hide the input for avoid change the data two gains?

Comment: do you mean to make the field readonly?

Comment: put your code here you have tried

Comment: why to print them in inputs if you don't want to change the values?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed No, I want do. If row == "" show input else show label. I want edit it data only 1 gain

Comment: @Mohammad Because I want the user can change the data only 1 gain, then cant change data

Comment: @GufranHasan Hello, I have only that to print the row

Comment: @LorenaKING, you should use `empty()` and `isset()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I unterstand your question. You can put the condition as:

```
<?php if(!empty($row['ID'])){ ?>
<input type="text" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">
<?php }else{ ?>
<label><?php echo $row['ID'];?></label>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(!empty($row['AGE'])){ ?>
<input type="text" name="AGE" value="<?php echo $row['AGE'];?>">
<?php }else{ ?>
<label><?php echo $row['AGE'];?></label>
<?php } ?>
```

Note: `empty()` function first checks if variable and then it checks emptiness

Answer (score 0):

you can use css by display:hidden and make lable on that place.